# Paperclip for Rails 4 creates NULL records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

It is taking me all day to config paperclip. I have copied everything from github. I am using devise and rails 4. This is my edit user view, I have added multipart:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true }) do |f| %> 
<%= f.label 'Add an image' %>
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
```

In my show view, I have

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
```

This shows the default missing image I Set up in user.rb.I cloned [paperclip demo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip_demo) and ran it and it works fine on my machine. 
I installed imagemagick correctly and jpeg decoder.
This is my user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar
letsrate_rater

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "50x50>" }, :default_url => "avatar/missing.jpg"

 validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

and my users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def create
  User.create(user_params)
end
private
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar)
end
end
```

Also paperclip doesn't create public/avatars and public/system folders and files?
Help!

Comment: When you upload your image, you don't get any error messages in the application log, do you?

Comment: I used to get Unpermitted parameters: avatar . It seems to have gone now.

Comment: Nothing in Logs just: Started GET "/assets/avatar/missing.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-22 18:08:12 +0200

Comment: Shouldn't you tell your view to use thumb or medium?

Comment: Is your `users` db table getting populated with data? If not, it means your file is not being passed correctly, if so, it might be an issue with Paperclip

Comment: sorted it out by changing default devise registrations controller and adding custom update and create mehtods.